# Find Control inside Grid Row

Tags: c#, asp.net, view, grid

i m using parent child grid and on child grid i m doing Show / hide threw java script. and child grid i bind run time with Templatecolumns like

```
GridView NewDg = new GridView();
NewDg.ID = "dgdStoreWiseMenuStock";

TemplateField TOTAL = new TemplateField();
TOTAL.HeaderTemplate = new BusinessLogic.GridViewTemplateTextBox(ListItemType.Header, "TOTAL",e.Row.RowIndex );
TOTAL.HeaderStyle.Width = Unit.Percentage(5.00);
TOTAL.ItemTemplate = new BusinessLogic.GridViewTemplateTextBox(ListItemType.Item, "TOTAL", e.Row.RowIndex);
NewDg.Columns.Add(TOTAL);

NewDg.DataSource = ds;
NewDg.DataBind();


NewDg.Columns[1].Visible = false;
NewDg.Columns[2].Visible = false;

System.IO.StringWriter sw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htw = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(sw);
NewDg.RenderControl(htw);
```

Now I have one TextBox inside Grid named "TOTAL" I want to Find This TextBox and wanna get its value.

How can Get it ?

Answer (score 5):

You could get the TextBox control inside the corresponding cell of the GridView, using the `Controls` property or the `FindControl(string id)` method:

```
TextBox txtTotal = gv.Rows[index].cells[0].Controls[0] as TextBox;
```

or

```
TextBox txtTotal = gv.Rows[index].cells[0].Controls[0].FindControl("TOTAL") as TextBox;
```

where index could be 0 for the first row, or an iterator inside a for loop.

Alternatively, you can use a foreach loop over the GridView's rows:

```
foreach(GridViewRow row in gv.Rows)
{
    TextBox txtTotal = row.cells[0].Controls[0].FindControl("TOTAL") as TextBox;
    string value = txtTotal.Text;

    // Do something with the textBox's value
}
```

Besides, you have to keep in mind that, if you're creating the GridView dynamically (and not declaratively in the web form), you won't be able to get this control after a page postback.

There is a great *4 Guys from Rolla* article on the subject: [Dynamic Web Controls, Postbacks, and View State](https://web.archive.org/web/20210330142645/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/092904-1.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

As you know you may get TextBox value for example for the first row and the first cell:

```
((TextBox) dgdStoreWiseMenuStock.Rows[0].Cells[0].Controls[1]).Text;
```

or change the index of control put 0 if the above line dosen't work.

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
 TextBox txtTotal = (TextBox)gv.Rows[index].cells[0].FindControl("TOTAL");
 string value = txtTotal.Text;
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to find the control inside the gridview use foreach loop to find the rows

```
 foreach (GridViewRow row in Gridname.Rows)
 {
      TextBox txttotal = (TextBox)row.FindControl("textboxid_inside_grid");
      string var = txttotal.Text;

      Response.Write("Textbox value = " + var);
 }
```