# ASP.Net Get Values ArgumentOutOfRangeException Thrown

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I'm trying to loop through a gridview and save all the items in it at once. However I have a problem getting the values from the dropdownlist and textbox. I get this error each time:

```
ArgumentOutOfRangeException was caught. Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
```

Here's the code I'm using:

```
foreach (GridViewRow gvr in gvInvalidOrgs.Rows)
{
   try
    {
     org_code = Convert.ToInt32(gvr.Cells[0].Text);
     division = ((DropDownList)gvr.Cells[1].Controls[0]).SelectedValue;
     org_description = (((TextBox)gvr.Cells[2].Controls[0]).Text);
    }
    ...
}
```

Both the textbox and the dropdownlists are dynamically created on rowbound if that matters.

TIA

Comment: You'd be better servied using GridViewRow.FindControl() and looking for the control by name, rather than referencing it by index using Controls[index]  You may need to convert columns to TemplateColumns to get it to work, but it's easier and less error prone in my experience.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewrow.findcontrol.aspx  also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1965835/find-control-inside-grid-row

Comment: Don't create them in `RowDataBound` but in `RowCreated`. The former will be called only when the GridView is databound. The latter is called on every postback.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing precisely which line the exception is thrown on, it's hard to diagnose with equal precision, but what's likely happening is that you're looking for a control in a cell that doesn't have any controls.

How could this come about?  Well, since you are creating the controls in `RowDataBound`, if you don't bind your grid on every postback (and I'm not recommending that you do) your dynamically-added controls won't be recreated on postback.  The posted data will include values for those controls, and ViewState will contain data for those controls, but if you don't recreate those controls on every postback, those controls won't exist when you attempt to access their values.

But you don't have to rebind to recreate the controls.  As Mr. Schmelter says in his comment, if you move your creation of the controls from the `RowDataBound` to the `RowCreated` event handler, they will be created when the grid rows are re-created on postback.

Comment: Thank you both for that help. The exception isn't being thrown any more but I can't get the value from the dropdownlist. I use this to capture the value but it doesn't seem to work for some reason. The value never changes.
`division = ((DropDownList)gvr.Cells[1].Controls[0]).SelectedValue;`

Comment: When are you checking the value?  At what stage of the page's life cycle?

Comment: I check the value upon a button click after the page has been loaded and the user selects a value and enters data into the textbox. The textbox's value is captured just fine.

Comment: How do you create the dropdownlist's values?  Do you bind it to something?

Comment: `protected void gvInvalidOrgs_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)  
{  
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)  
{  
DropDownList ddlDivision = new DropDownList();  
ListItem blank = new ListItem("", "-1");  
ddlDivision.Items.Add(blank);  
foreach (DataRow dr in dtDivisions.Rows)  
{  
ListItem li = new ListItem(dr["division"].ToString(), dr["division"].ToString());  
ddlDivision.Items.Add(li);  
}  
e.Row.Cells[0].Controls.Add(ddlDivision);  
  
TextBox tbDescription = new TextBox();  
tbDescription.Width = 200;  
  
e.Row.Cells[1].Controls.Add(tbDescription);  
} 
}`

Comment: So the selected value is always -1?

Comment: Yes, no matter what its always -1. The selected index never seems to change either as I've stepped through it during debugging.

Comment: I've got an idea.  Assign the drop down list's ID property a value when you create it.  ("ddl1" will probably be fine.) IIRC, ASP.NET uses the ID to determine how to assign a value to a control in postback.  It may not be able to find your control to give the SelectedValue property its proper value!

Comment: I tried assigning `ddlDivision.ID="ddl1";` but it still doesn't seem to pick up the value.

Comment: You're assigning the ID before you add the control to the controls collection?  That's the last thing I can think of right now.

Comment: Yes I was. I have actually gotten it to work by binding on each postback and using the rowbound event. This was something that someone needed semi-urgently so I know it isn't the cleanest way of doing it, but its working for now. I really appreciate your help on this one. I'll come back to it at some point again.