# How to get image from GridView using GridView_RowCommand event in c# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

i am doing edit operation inside GridView using c# ASP.NET.i need when user will click on edit button all data will retrive from that row and display in text box but here i am unable to display the image.I am explaining my code below.

> faq.aspx:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <label for="question" accesskey="T"><span class="required">*</span> Question</label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"  size="30" value="" name="question" ></asp:TextBox>
        <div id="noty" style="display:none;" runat="server"></div>
        <label for="answer" accesskey="A"><span class="required">*</span> Answer</label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"  size="30" value="" name="answer" ></asp:TextBox>
        <div id="Div1" style="display:none;" runat="server"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 bannerimagefile">
        <label for="insertimage" accesskey="B"><span class="required">*</span> Insert Image</label>
        <asp:FileUpload runat="server" class="filestyle" data-size="lg" name="insertimage" id="FileUpload1" onchange="previewFile()" />
        <label for="bannerimage" accesskey="V"><span class="required">*</span> View Image</label>
        <div style="padding-bottom:10px;">
            <asp:Image ID="Image3" runat="server" border="0" name="bannerimage" style="width:70px; height:70px;"   />
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit" class="submit" 
            onclick="Button1_Click" />
        </div>
</div>

<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" Width="100%" CssClass="table table-striped table-bordered margin-top-zero" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand" >
    <Columns>
       <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Sl No">
       <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:Label ID="faqid" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("FAQ_ID") %>'></asp:Label>
       </ItemTemplate>
       </asp:TemplateField>
       <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Question" >
       <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:Label ID="question" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Question") %>'></asp:Label>
       </ItemTemplate>
       </asp:TemplateField>
       <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Answer" >
       <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:Label ID="answer" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Answer") %>'></asp:Label>
       </ItemTemplate>
       </asp:TemplateField>
       <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Image" >
       <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" border="0" name="bannerimage" style="width:70px; height:70px;" ImageUrl='<%# "/Upload/" + Convert.ToString(Eval("Image")) %>'  /> 
       </ItemTemplate>
       </asp:TemplateField>
       <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action" >
       <ItemTemplate>
       <!--<a href="" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" class="btn btn-xs btn-success" data-original-title="Edit" id="editbtn" ><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>
       <a href=" " data-toggle="tooltip" title="" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" data-original-title="Delete"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a> -->
            <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" class="btn btn-xs btn-success" data-original-title="Edit" CommandName="DoEdit" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("FAQ_ID") %>' ><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></asp:HyperLink>
             <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink2" runat="server" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" data-original-title="Delete" CommandName="DoDelete" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("FAQ_ID") %>' ><i class="fa fa-times"></i></asp:HyperLink>
           </ItemTemplate>
       </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

> faq.aspx.cs:

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    int faqID = int.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
    switch (e.CommandName)
    {
        case "doEdit":
            {
                int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
                TextBox1.Text = GridView1.Rows[index].Cells[1].Text;
                TextBox2.Text = GridView1.Rows[index].Cells[2].Text;
                HiddenField1.Value = GridView1.Rows[index].Cells[0].Text;
                Image3.ImageUrl=
                Button1.Text = "Update";
            }
    }
}
```

Here i need the image will retrive and set to `image3` id.Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Have you tried using "FindControl"? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1965835/find-control-inside-grid-row? You will get the image control and from there you should be able to get its URL

Answer (score 0):

WHere is image3; it's not in your snippet.  Please include that, but if it's in the grid, then you do:

```
var img3 = (Image)GridView1.Rows[index].Cells[X].FindControl("Image3");
img3.ImageUrl = "XYZ";
```

Direct references only work when on the page outside of a container.  If inside a container, you have to use FindControl (such as detailsview.findcontrol) or if a repeatable list, you have to use FindControl from the row (or in the case of the grid, the cell).

Comment: @ Brian : i have added you can check my post now.

Comment: You should be able to refer to image3 directly.  Make sure image3 is in the designer file.

Comment: @ Brian: Another problem here i am unable to fetch any data right now using `OnRowCommand` event can you find the solution.

Comment: RowCommand only has bound data during initial binding.  After post back, dataitem for row is null.

Answer (score 0):

Get row index like this:

```
 GridViewRow gvr = (GridViewRow)(((HyperLink)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer);

    int index= gvr.RowIndex;
```

// to get image url

```
 string url =  ((Image)gvr.FindControl("Image3")).ImageUrl;    
    Image3.ImageUrl= url;
```