# htHow to find control of Textbox in table cell which is inside Gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview and I have few records and I have one table cell at the top inside the gridview with a textbox and a button  to filter the records. How do I find the control of that textbox.

```
protected void GridView2_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
        {
            GridViewRow HeaderGridRow = new GridViewRow(0, 1, DataControlRowType.Header, DataControlRowState.Normal);
            TableCell HeaderCell = new TableCell();

            HeaderCell.Text = "";
            TextBox abc = new TextBox();
            HeaderCell.Controls.Add(abc);
            HeaderCell.ColumnSpan = 3;
            HeaderGridRow.Cells.Add(HeaderCell);

            HeaderCell = new TableCell();
            HeaderCell.Text = "";
            TextBox search = new TextBox();
            search.ID = "search1";
            HeaderCell.Controls.Add(search);
            HeaderCell.ColumnSpan = 3;
            HeaderGridRow.Cells.Add(HeaderCell);
            Control ctrl = HeaderGridRow.Cells[1].Controls[0];
            TextBox tc = ctrl as TextBox;


            HeaderCell = new TableCell();

            Button btn_chk = new Button();
            btn_chk.Text = "go";
            HeaderCell.Controls.Add(btn_chk);
            HeaderCell.ColumnSpan = 1;
            btn_chk.Click += new EventHandler(btnClick);
            HeaderGridRow.Cells.Add(HeaderCell);

            //btn_chk.CommandName = "btn_chk";

            GridView2.Controls[0].Controls.AddAt(0, HeaderGridRow);


        }
    }

        html part

         <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server"            OnRowCreated="GridView2_RowCreated">   
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:TemplateField>

     <%--   <HeaderTemplate>
     Planning Id<br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="txt_planningid" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </HeaderTemplate>--%>                     
                            <HeaderTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="Label9" runat="server" Text="S.No"></asp:Label>
                            </HeaderTemplate>

                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server" Text="<%#Container.DataItemIndex+1 %> "></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>

                        </asp:TemplateField>

                    </Columns>

                </asp:GridView>
```

I have added two textboxes and one button using table cell in rowcreated event..

Comment: Have you seen this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1965835/find-control-inside-grid-row

Comment: yes i have checked.gridview.rows[] returns the number of rows of records.i want  control of textbox which is above  the header part of gridview.i want to use that textbox to filter the records in the gridview.

Comment: Could you post your HTML

Comment: ya i have updated..

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're after,

Add a RowDataBound event to your Gridview

```
OnRowDataBound="GridView2_RowDataBound"
```

Handle the event using the RowDataBound event and find the Textbox:

```
protected void GridView2_RowDataBound(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
    {
        // Find the textbox
        TextBox abc = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("abc");

    }
}
```

Comment: actually in gridview GridView2 row created event i have created  another gridview  'headergridrow' dynamically which has a textbox inside.i need to find the control of that textbox.