# The name does not exists in the current context asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015

I am using vs 2015 update 3,
I created a website but while writing a code i get this error which says,

> “The name 'control' does not exists in the current context”.

this control inside grid-view control
I would like if you can help me to understand the error and tell me how I can fix it.

This is my grid-view :

```
 <div id="mainform">
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
     <Columns>
       <asp:TemplateField Visible="false">
           <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblProID" Visible="false" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ID")%>' />
             </ItemTemplate>
       </asp:TemplateField>
       <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="projects" ItemStyle-Width="150" >
           <ItemTemplate>
             <asp:Label ID="lblProjectName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ProjectName")%>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
         <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtProjectName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ProjectName") %>'></asp:TextBox>
         </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
 </asp:GridView>
```

when i call or write lblProjectName it give me this error that i mentioned it before

> The name does not exists in the current context

Comment: Please add your code also.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Name does not exist in the current context](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19027025/name-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context)

Comment: you'll need to access it via rows property for this grid view, using row index and then try to search for this control in the row cells
this is a possible solution to your question if I understood correctly 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1965835/find-control-inside-grid-row

Comment: i update my question